# Webpack outputs "require" despite target=node16

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

I'm trying to get Webpack to output valid an ES6 module suitable for node.js 16.
I've made these updates to the Webpack config:

```
experiments = { outputModule: true };
output.module = true;
output.library.type = 'module';
target = "async-node16.13";
```

When looking at the build output, that seems to work for things imported from node:

```
/***/ "fs":
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_createRequire(import.meta.url)("fs");

/***/ }),
```

but not for things imported from node_modules:

```
/***/ "@godaddy/terminus":
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = require("@godaddy/terminus");

/***/ }),
```

Note that I don't have `"target": "module"` in my package.json because there are some .js files that I can't rename that have to be loaded as CommonJS. I do have that in the build folder where this output file is though.

Comment: we having same issue, any resolution?